# Puzzle: Find elements with specific LCM

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, puzzle

The task is to find numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_k \in \mathbb{N}$ with lcm$(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)=1980$ and with $a_1+a_2+...+a_k \leq 29$

Comment: Start by factoring $1980$.

Comment: $1980 = 2*2*3*3*5*11$

Comment: So $\operatorname{lcm}(4,9,5,11) = 1980$, using the prime powers.